# Validating Oracle SQL statement from OCCI / C++

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, occi

### Problem

We would like to validate that an Oracle SQL statement is syntactically correct, only references known tables, views, columns, etc.

### OCI for Oracle 12c – possible to parse only

Using OCI (Oracle Call Interface) for Oracle 12c it is possible to first create a statement using [`OCIStmtPrepare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci17msc001.htm#LNOCI17167) and then call [`OCIStmtExecute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci17msc001.htm#LNOCI17163) using the special mode `OCI_PARSE_ONLY`. This will cause Oracle to parse the statement without actually executing it.

### OCCI for Oracle 12 – impossible?

Now, we are using OCCI (Oracle C++ Call Interface) for Oracle 12c. It seems there is no way to force Oracle to parse the statement without also executing it. When calling the [`Connection::createStatement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference010.htm#LNCPP20764) method and then calling [`Statement::status()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference030.htm#LNCPP21786) on the returned statement, Oracle will tell you that the statement is `PREPARED` but parsing the statement is deferred until the statement is actually executed calling e.g. [`Statement::execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference030.htm#LNCPP21621) so there does not seem to be a way to parse the statement without executing.

Is anybody aware of a way to parse without executing a SQL statement using OCCI for Oracle 12c?

Comment: I personally find OCCI a terrible library and a poorely designed wrapper around OCI. Enywhere I look, I see people using OCI, not OCCI - even for C++ development.

Comment: @SergeyA I can only agree with you, but right now I am stuck with OCCI.

Comment: Than you can't parse-only your statements on the server. Ok, the one thing you can do is to get the raw handle with `getOCIStatement()` and than call OCIExecute on it. I am not sure if it still is 'using OCCI'.

Comment: @SergeyA I also thought of that solution but I am really looking for a solution within OCCI (or an answer that says that is not possible).